# How do you describe someone who is very good at maintaining a home/doing household chores?

Tags: phrase-request, american-english, spoken-english

Females that are mostly home-based do house-hold chores very effectively and they're tend to be more pro at it. I looked up on the internet and the word I came across was "fine-fingered". I intend to use this term for "cooking, baking, sewing, doing bed with excellency" that basically connoted everything that comes under house-hold activities. Are there any more synonyms/ slangs?

I am trying to translate a word, and fine-fingered was the only option I found.

Comment: Um, that's a stereotype but in many western cultures it is considered to be outdated, limiting, and wrong. There is a movement away from the image of the "woman as the housewife" and towards an image of balanced family life where both spouses contribute in the home and financially. "Fine-fingered" is not a term I have ever heard. Please cite the source of this and what it claims to mean.

Comment: @catija that i know :) and im talking about eastern culture. Besides, males also help out in doing household chores :). I tried to translate that word and this word came out.

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing the term used for rhis quality, if anyone could please tell me

Comment: @Catija "fine fingered" describes being adept at (usually) intricate or delicate work. [Wherein he manifestly proved, that rhetoric and eloquence (as Plato saith) is an art which quickeneth men’s spirits at her pleasure, and her chiefest skill is to know how to move passions and affections throughly, which are as stops and sounds of the soul, that would be played upon with a **fine-fingered hand** of a cunning master.](http://www.bartleby.com/209/123.html) It's old-fashioned, and most of the uses I found appear to be romance novels.

Comment: Fine-fingered means dextrous, good at delicate crafting, etc. But this is available online. Domestic chores are not necessarily requisite of such skills (as opposed to jobs like surgeon). Maybe related to sewing, etc, but the question is unclear as it stands now.

Comment: The dictionary gives a rather clinical definition for [*homemaker*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/homemaker), but in actual usage, the word can have the kinds of connotations you're describing - doing the domestic job well with the intended end result of making the house (i.e. 'just' a place to stay) a home (somewhere people *want* to return each day - embraces emotional ties, feelings of security, etc) for the family. Is this something along the lines of what you're looking for? Or is it more strictly task-based excellence you're seeking to describe?

Comment: In English we say **making the bed(s)**  not **doing bed**.  It's a common difficulty with learners to idiomatically  use *make* and *do*.

Comment: @Catija Please note that my answer is Community Wiki. It would be good to have something like it on hand (with many additions!) should a question of this sort be posed in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fine-fingered](http://www.onelook.com/?w=fine-fingered&ls=a) gets no hits on *Onelook* (which searches dozens of dictionaries), and this suggests its usage is limited in  English, although [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/fine-fingered) includes it and defines it as

> Delicate in workmanship; expert at fine work.

This can apply to many things, but not  necessarily the activities you list. One doesn't have to be fine-fingered to make the bed or wash the dishes. It applies to activities of a more intricate nature, such as needlecraft or sculpting small, detailed objects out of wood or ivory.

Someone, whether male or female, can be called a [homemaker](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/homemaker), so you can say 'He (or she) is a good homemaker'. One's  skill in activities that involve the hand, whether they are sewing and cooking  or hunting and gardening, can be described as [handy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/handy) (see especially definition 3).

The ideal God-fearing woman is described in [Proverbs 31:10-31](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs+31%3A10-31&version=MSG), and shows such a person (it can also apply to males) as [industrious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/industrious) in important tasks & responsibilities outside of the home:

> A good woman is hard to find,
>       and worth far more than diamonds.
>   Her husband trusts her without reserve,
>       and never has reason to regret it.
>   Never spiteful, she treats him generously
>       all her life long.
>   She shops around for the best yarns and cottons,
>       and enjoys knitting and sewing.
>   She’s like a trading ship that sails to faraway places
>       and brings back exotic surprises.
>   She’s up before dawn, preparing breakfast
>       for her family and organizing her day.
>   She looks over a field and buys it,
>       then, with money she’s put aside, plants a garden.
>   First thing in the morning, she dresses for work,
>       rolls up her sleeves, eager to get started.
>   She senses the worth of her work,
>       is in no hurry to call it quits for the day.
>   She’s skilled in the crafts of home and hearth,
>       diligent in homemaking.
>   She’s quick to assist anyone in need,
>       reaches out to help the poor.
>   She doesn’t worry about her family when it snows;
>       their winter clothes are all mended and ready to wear.
>   She makes her own clothing,
>       and dresses in colorful linens and silks.
>   Her husband is greatly respected
>       when he deliberates with the city fathers.
>   She designs gowns and sells them,
>       brings the sweaters she knits to the dress shops.
>   Her clothes are well-made and elegant,
>       and she always faces tomorrow with a smile.
>   When she speaks she has something worthwhile to say,
>       and she always says it kindly.
>   She keeps an eye on everyone in her household,
>       and keeps them all busy and productive.
>   Her children respect and bless her;
>       her husband joins in with words of praise:
>   “Many women have done wonderful things,
>       but you’ve outclassed them all!”
>   Charm can mislead and beauty soon fades.
>       The woman to be admired and praised
>       is the woman who lives in the Fear-of-God.
>   Give her everything she deserves!
>       Festoon her life with praises!

Thus, "a good woman"  was not confined  within the  house in ancient Israel, although in some cultures they are even today.

Comment: This is from Jewish scripture. There are millions of people in the world who have no idea what "Proverbs" is, or even what the Torah is. The citation, which is excellent, should credit the source explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for **domestic** (/dəˈmɛstɪk/), It means when you are devoted to home life.

> belonging or relating to the home, house, or family:
>   domestic chores/duties/arrangements

**domestic** can have others meaning, you can check its on [Cambridge Dictionary.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/domestic)

Comment: But isnt this term used for servants?

Comment: **domestic can have others meaning**

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a convenient word for this, but the idiomatic expression that's most widely used (by those who have no fear for their own personal safety) is

> You'd make someone a lovely wife.

This is intended as a compliment, but there are few better ways to insult a modern woman than to suggest that her life's achievements to date are as nothing compared to a future of cooking, washing and darning socks.

Answer (score -1):

Let us imagine for a moment [**Angela Merkel**](http://www.rferl.org/content/putin-merkel-g20-summit-talks-ukraine-syria/27967346.html) at her knitting and tatting. The subtlety of her antimacassars is sublime.

But hark! What vision now intrudes? It is [**Margaret Atwood,**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Atwood) and, first adjusting her white cap, she industriously arranges the pleats in the curtains until they are *just so!*

No sooner are we accustomed to this exemplar of feminine virtue than the door bursts open, admitting [**Dominique Crenn.**](http://www.ateliercrenn.com/) She has just come from the market, and greets us with a melodious

> *"We are about to prepare Sahib's evening repast."*

Now, instead, let us envision [**Serena Williams**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serena_Williams) delicately dusting the last specks from our pristine countertop. She says:

> "I have an answer to your question, and there is nothing *fine* fingered about it."